# How to access the topLayoutGuide from a view file in MVC pattern in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, anchor

I'm trying to add a stack view to one of the view controller files in my project. Since the view controller file has a navigation bar, I want to pin the stack view to the bottom of the navigation bar using the topLayoutGuide.
To show the VC, I wrote the following code.

```
let vc = CreateEventViewController()
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
nc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
self.present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil
```

In the CreateEventViewController class, which is the view controller file, I wrote the following code.

```
class CreateEventViewController: UIViewController {
    private let createEventView = CreateEventView() // -> this is the view file
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavbar()
        view.addSubview(createEventView)
        createEventView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: view.bounds.size)
    }
    
    func setupNavbar() {
        self.title = "here is a nav bar"
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPressed))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(addEventPressed))
    }
```

In the view file, I add the following code to add the stack view with a textfield & a date picker in it.

```
class CreateEventView: UIView {

    lazy var eventTitleTextField: UITextField = {
        // codes for adding textfield
        return textField
    }()

    lazy var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
        // codes for adding datepicker
        return datePicker
    }()

    lazy var VStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 10
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        return stackView
    }()

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.addSubview(VStackView)
        addItemToStackView()
    }

    func addItemToStackView() {
        let items = [eventTitleTextField, datePicker]
        for i in 0...items.count - 1 {
            VStackView.addArrangedSubview(items[i])
        }
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        VStackView.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, leading: self.leadingAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, trailing: self.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 40, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)) // this is the custom function but I'm just adding constraints.

}
```

After building the app, I see the following image on the screen.
[image]

As you can see, the textField in the stack view is partially covered by the navigation bar. I wanted to set the top anchor of the Stackview in the CreateEventView class as something like `self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor`, but I get an error saying Value of type 'CreateEventView' has no member 'topLayoutGuide', and I just manually add a constant to lower the stackview, like in `padding: .init(top: 40, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`, for now.

So my question is how can I pin the stack view's top to the bottom of the navigation bar?
Am I wrong if I pin the view file to the origin of (0,0), like `createEventView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: view.bounds.size)`, without considering the height of the navigation bar? I mean, should I pin the view somehow like `createEventView.frame = CGRect(origin: x: 0, y: height of the navigation bar (???), size: view.bounds.size)`

Comment: Top Layout Guide is deprecated. Use [Safe Area](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)

Comment: @RickyMo Thank you so much! 
I just changed the anchor of the stack view to VStackView.anchor(top: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor) and it's working fine ;)

Comment: @RickyMo 
If I have a navigation bar in the VC, the view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor automatically becomes the bottom of the navigation bar??

Answer (score 2):

As Ricky mentioned, I need to use a safe area, not the top layout guide.